# How to solve large numbers if they are a prime number? Eg Is 3599 a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

I am reading the book, the Flash Boys, and in it is a trick interview question as per the title. The person solves the problem so:

```
3599 = (3600 – 1) = 
(60² – 1²) = 
(60 – 1) (60 + 1)
= 59 × 61
3599 = 59 × 61 not a prime number.
```

I am curious about this part (60² – 1²) = (60 – 1) (60 + 1)
Is this some kind of a rule?

Comment: $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ is an identity. Try expanding the RHS.

Comment: Wow, great answer and formula.

Comment: Just a side note: this doesn’t make the general case of testing for prime-ness easy. In the case of $3599,$ it is easy to represent it as a difference of squares suitable for this trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well-known identity known as the "difference of squares" identity:

$$a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$$

You can see this algebraically by expanding the right-hand side:

$$(a-b)(a+b) = a^2 + ab - ab - b^2 = a^2 - b^2$$

You can also see it geometrically: suppose we have a large pink square as below, with side length $a$, and a square in the corner with side length $b$. You can come up with several expressions with this knowledge for the pink area.

- You can take the whole square, and remove the blue bit, getting $a^2 - b^2$
- You can add up the smaller pink rectangles individually, getting $(a-b)^2 + 2b(a-b)$. Factor out $(a-b)$ from that, and you get $(a-b)((a-b) + 2b) = (a-b)(a+b)$.

[image]